# Ubuntu 18.04 immediately logs out with a specific user

Tags: crash, logout, ubuntu-18.04, gnome-shell-extensions

My Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't allow me to log in with GNOME. Immediately after logging in, it seems that a crash occurs and I'm back at the log in page. If I try with a different user it works.

I found this in /var/log/syslog

*Dec 10 10:13:38 y-server indicator-multi[13236]: indicator-multiload: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.*

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

I tried to uninstall the indicator-multiload and now everything is working. Hope this can help someone else.

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem for me, savior!